# sqlalchemy / pandas - How do I create an sqlalchemy `selectable` to pass to pd.read_sql?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm completely new to sqlalchemy, and I've been trying to better understand how `pd.read_sql` can be used.

I've succesfully run the following:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( index=range(10,30), data=np.random.rand(20, 10) )
eng = sa.create_engine('sqlite:///test.db')
df.reset_index().to_sql('test_table', eng, index=False)
df2 = pd.read_sql( 'test_table' , eng ) # Don't understand this function
```

I've figured out I can just load whatever I stored in the table by passing the table name as the first argument of `pd.read_sql` but what if I wanted to load only the elements for which column `index` is greater than some number.

**Question**

How do I create an sqlalchemy `selectable` for the first argument of  `pd.read_sql` to only load a subset of the database/table?

*Comment:*
In this case I know that this is trivial to do after I've loaded df2 but if the size of the db is very large I'd like to avoid having to load the entire db in memory first.

Comment: Would using SQL be an option?

Comment: Have you read the [Selecting](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#selecting) section of the tutorial?

Comment: @BobHaffner, why did you delete your answer? It perfectly answers this question - isn't it?

Comment: I posted an answer, if anyone has a better "best practice" one to post please do so

Comment: Hi @MaxU the question was aimed at Selectables so I decided to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the table in 3 different ways. (Not sure what the differences are).

then using the `.select()` method on that table and the `.where` on that result gets what I want.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
eng = sa.create_engine('sqlite:///test.db')
# First way to load table
m = sa.MetaData()
m.reflect(bind=eng)
t1 = m.tables['test_table']

# Second way
m2 = sa.MetaData(bind=eng)
t2 = sa.Table('test_table', m2, autoload=True)

# Third way
t3 = sa.Table('test_table', sa.MetaData(), autoload_with=eng)

# I can then use either of the t's to do the following
df3 = pd.read_sql(t.select().where(t.c.index > 15), eng)
```

Comment: I couldn't get your 3rd way to work.  Also, a potential 4th would be SQL.  `sql =  'select * from test_table where "index" > 15'
df4 = pd.read_sql( sql , eng )`  Doesn't require a MetaData or a Table object and is faster on your dataset.  Good stuff by the way.  I didn't know about Selectables

Comment: Should work now, added the (), haven't tested it though